# Analyzer dependencies from class in IDEA or in another java tool

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm looking the way to understand full influence of changing some class. For example I added new field to DTO class. It is needed to find all web-services and methods that are affected by this change. For a now I need to find all classes that extend changed class, all classes that aggregate this class or any of its children, all classes that use type of changed class or of its children, etc. Risk to lose affected web-services is very high. And if I lose even one web-services it means bug during integration process.

Is there tool that makes this process automatic?

Comment: If you did not write it, then it does not exist.

Comment: For example our integration tests uses special implementation of WebServiceTemplate which checks the marshalled request and returns a defined response, and our backend simulation component (used for automatic regression tests and development) does the same thing.

Comment: Yes, it's good way. But sometimes you have huge project that were created not by you. And these guys didn't like tests.

Comment: I was in the same situation... I develop a legacy payment platform which earns millions and it had nothing that checked outgoing requests into billing systems...

Comment: Just recently I wanted to add an optional element, which would be used only for compatible systems, and guess what, Axis 1.1 always sends it everywhere, so it would break everyone. There is nothing that would tell you that the thing you are trying to do will not work with a specific framework.  Regression tests is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to use the `Dependency Matrix`, which is available under the `Analyze` menu from the action `Analyze Dependency Matrix`. This shows you efferent and afferent dependencies, along with metrics that can be used to infer the strength of the dependency.

Comment: No, this is the different tool. It works for all projects and shows only explicit dependency.